# Do regular public relays understand pluggable transports?

Tags: pluggable-transports

In order to use a pluggable transport, is one required to connect through a Tor *bridge*, or do regular public ingress *relays* also support transports (such as *obfs* N) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to use bridges.

While it's possible for relays to run a pluggable transport server and connect them to their ORPort, theres no means to distribute information and what pluggable transports they provide and where. Theres also no real reason that they should either.

So while it's not *required* it is the only way you'll have some delivery mechanism for the necessary `Bridge` lines to use them. There's also no real method for relays to use them in connections between themselves. A Tor relay *should* be able to make connections to any other relay, uncensored, so pluggable transports would only be a hinderance.